# Como exibir um array multidimensional sem utilizar loop?

Tags: java, array

Ao tentar executar o trecho abaixo:

```
int[] vetor = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(vetor));
```

O array é exibido normalmente como `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` mas se eu tentar com um array bidimensional, conforme o trecho abaixo:

```
int[][] matriz = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {8, 10, 12, 14}};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(matriz));
```

O resultado é `[[I@7852e922, [I@4e25154f]` e os valores do array não são exibidos.

Há alguma forma de exibir um array bidimensional direto no `System.out.println` sem ter que fazer laços ou sobrescrever métodos, como ocorreu no código com o array simples?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mediante códigos tanto `forEach` com `lambda`, quanto o método `deepToString` do `Arrays` utilizam `foreach` e `for` respectivamente internamente em seus códigos, não havendo outro meio de exibir um `array` (simples ou multidimensional) sem que acontece o `loop`. Concluindo que sem um `loop`, não tem possibilidades de apresentar em um texto os dados contidos em um `array`, e os códigos de `classes` podem encapsular isso para ficar transparente ao desenvolvedor, escondendo (omitindo) a realidade do código.

#### Códigos:

> `forEach` com `lambda`

```
@Override
public void forEach(Consumer<? super E> action) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(action);
    for (E e : a) {
        action.accept(e);
    }
}
```

> `deepToString`

```
public static String deepToString(Object[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";

    int bufLen = 20 * a.length;
    if (a.length != 0 && bufLen <= 0)
        bufLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(bufLen);
    deepToString(a, buf, new HashSet<Object[]>());
    return buf.toString();
}

private static void deepToString(Object[] a, StringBuilder buf,
                                 Set<Object[]> dejaVu) {
    if (a == null) {
        buf.append("null");
        return;
    }
    int iMax = a.length - 1;
    if (iMax == -1) {
        buf.append("[]");
        return;
    }

    dejaVu.add(a);
    buf.append('[');
    for (int i = 0; ; i++) {

        Object element = a[i];
        if (element == null) {
            buf.append("null");
        } else {
            Class<?> eClass = element.getClass();

            if (eClass.isArray()) {
                if (eClass == byte[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((byte[]) element));
                else if (eClass == short[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((short[]) element));
                else if (eClass == int[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((int[]) element));
                else if (eClass == long[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((long[]) element));
                else if (eClass == char[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((char[]) element));
                else if (eClass == float[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((float[]) element));
                else if (eClass == double[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((double[]) element));
                else if (eClass == boolean[].class)
                    buf.append(toString((boolean[]) element));
                else { // element is an array of object references
                    if (dejaVu.contains(element))
                        buf.append("[...]");
                    else
                        deepToString((Object[])element, buf, dejaVu);
                }
            } else {  // element is non-null and not an array
                buf.append(element.toString());
            }
        }
        if (i == iMax)
            break;
        buf.append(", ");
    }
    buf.append(']');
    dejaVu.remove(a);
}
```

O exemplo que passo seria Java 8, com [lambda](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.br/2013/11/java-8-tutorials-resources-and-examples-lambda-expression-stream-api-functional-interfaces.html):

```
int[][] matriz = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, {8, 10, 12, 14}};
Arrays.asList(matriz).forEach((i) -> { System.out.println(Arrays.toString(i)); });
```

[***Exemplo Online***](http://ideone.com/r1Xjwa)

Referencia:

- [Java 8 first steps with Lambdas and Streams](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2013/10/java-8-first-steps-lambdas-streams/)

Comment: A resposta é válida e agora está até mais completa(já até deixei meu voto), mas em relação a necessidade de laço, a questão que eu abordei quanto a ele é justamente não termos que escrevê-lo, se o método faz o laço internamente, como uma característica nativa da linguagem, você não precisou escrevê-lo "na mão".

Comment: Entendi @diegofm, nenhuma das duas formas, precisa escrever o `for` ou `foreach` ná mão são métodos (um com o nome bem sugestivo) que internamente nada mais é do que um laço. Quanto fui questionado queria passar essa informação na forma simples para que todos entendam que muitas vezes procuramos algum código e nada mais é do que faze-lo de forma simples. Obrigado pelo comentário.

Answer (score 9):

Basta usar o método `deepToString(Object[] a)`;

```
int array[][] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Saída:

> [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

Answer (score 1):

Você deve colocar referente o primeiro array de array, e a posição que desejar e assim por diante.

```
System.out.println(matriz[0][0]);//saida 1  
System.out.println(matriz[0][1]); //saida 2  
System.out.println(matriz[0][2]); //saida 3
```

Comment: É uma solução válida, mas não é muito viável dependendo do tamanho do array, ou do numero de "dimensoes" que ele tiver.